# How to simplify this trignometric expression: $4( 3 \sin \theta)( 3 \cos \theta)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I was given a circle with a radius of $3$ and in it was a rectangle and an angle $\theta$ extending from the $x$ axis to up with coordinates of $(3 \cos \theta, 3 \sin \theta)$ and the question asks me to show that the area of the triangle represented by $A$ is equal to $18 \sin 2 \theta$. I figured that the the rectangle has $8$ triangles so using the angle and the coordinates I would find the area of one triangle and multiple it by $8$. So I ended up with $$(8)(.5) b h= (8)(.5)(3 \cos \theta) (3 \sin\theta) = 4( 3 \sin \theta)( 3 \cos \theta).$$ How do you represent this as $18 \sin 2 \theta$?

Thanks and sorry for the question being too long.

Comment: Without a diagram here it is going to be hard to understand what's going on....

Comment: Just use the double-angle formula: $2 \sin\theta \cos\theta = \sin 2\theta$.

Comment: can you show me how to use the double angle formula for that as I am mixed up by how to use it on this specific case, that is my problem from the beginning.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 9/4 in stead of 18?

Comment: its a question from an old IB exam so i am pretty sure its 18

Comment: @user134345: It's all about appropriate grouping. $$4\;(3\sin\theta)\;(3\cos\theta) = 36 \sin\theta\cos\theta = 18\cdot 2\sin\theta\cos\theta = 18 \sin2\theta$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Blue I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than referring to the area, use the trig identity $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$ to write 
\begin{equation*}
4(3\sin(\theta))(3\cos(\theta)) \\
=36\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \\
=18\cdot 2 \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \\
=18\sin(2\theta)
\end{equation*}
hence the result. I am not sure how it could be done with this trig identity.

Answer (score 0):

$\text{Area}= \frac 1 2 3\sin\theta 3\cos\theta$

Use $\sin\theta \cos\theta = \frac 1 2\sin 2\theta$

$=\frac 9 4 \sin 2\theta$

Multiply by $8$ to get $18\sin 2\theta$

Comment: Almost correct just that the sides are $6\sin{\theta}$ and $6\cos{\theta}$ respectively. Edit it and you are home free.

Comment: Thank you, but I think you understood my question wrong Blue in the comments above just answered it.

Comment: @user134345 You just had to multiply by 8 in my answer.